# How to protect credentials or keys used in plain text within program?

Tags: database, security

Lately I've been connecting to a database connected on the cloud (AWS) with ExpressJS. The connection is defined as follows: (Source: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html)

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'dbuser',
  password : 's3kreee7',
  database : 'my_db'
});
```

On AWS I've been connecting through environmental variables through the AWS process:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
    user: process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.RDS_PORT
});
```

Although very convenient when running on AWS, this becomes a pain if I wanted to run/troubleshoot my code locally, so then I ended up inserting the actual values for connecting to my database manually, similar to the first code example shown in my post.

With a username and password listed in plain text this seems really insecure. Certainly any version control of your product would have to be private or anybody could get credentials for your database, and even then you might not want your credentials saved in version control history. What are the best practices surrounding this? Is there someway that people typically connect to databases or secure resources within their code that require credentials, keys, or other secure information? Is there a standard?

This is the best idea I came up with on my own, referencing examples above:

```
host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME || hostVariablePulledFromLocalFile
```

This would connect to the DB if on AWS, and if not use some variable stored in a local text or json file, which contains the credentials and other important information. That way you could push to version control & not have your credentials be there (of course excluding the information file from the repo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely don't put secrets (like database credentials) in your source tree. Not only does that compromise those credentials, but it also makes it impossible to deploy the same code in development and production environments.

A common standard for Javascript applications is [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv). It looks like you may be using this already, but what you may not have realized is that the `.env` file should **not** be in source control -- it should be excluded with `.gitignore`, and installed separately as part of your deployment process. This way, you can have your development credentials present on your own machine, and production credentials in production.

For Amazon RDS in particular, [you may be able to use instance IAM to handle database authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html). If that isn't suitable, another option worth investigating may be [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/).

Comment: I see...AWS is very new to me, I wasn't sure how the environmental variables worked on AWS, which I'm assuming now is through a .env file. This must be an internal implementation on AWS, as I had to enter the info on AWS but it must set that part up for you. I'll look into implementing my own .env file locally and see how that works out and get back to this post at that time.

Comment: The .env worked really well actually! Thanks. Now I also understand how AWS is working (I was wondering how it did that), and I got my code setup to take the variable as AWS.ENV.VAR || LOCAL.ENV.VAR, so I don't have to change my code to test locally or on development server!